# Taskflow functionality

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am new from Oracle MAF. In my task flow 5 fields are there. The first one in Questionnaire page.

In this questionnaire page:

- create Questionnaire
- List Questionnaire
- Search Questionnaire
- Reports

these four fields are there. If I click any one of the field, I want to go that page. Like if I click create Questionnaire, I want to go to create Questionnaire page.

Please help anyone how can I do this. I am using the following code for taskflow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<adfc-mobile-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller" version="1.0">
  <task-flow-definition id="Questionnaire-task-flow">
    <default-activity>Questionnaire</default-activity>
    <view id="Questionnaire">
      <page>/Questionnaire.amx</page>
    </view>
    <view id="create">
      <page>/create.amx</page>
    </view>
    <view id="list">
      <page>/list.amx</page>
    </view>
    <view id="search">
      <page>/search.amx</page>
    </view>
    <view id="reports">
      <page>/reports.amx</page>
    </view>
    <control-flow-rule id="__12">
      <from-activity-id>Questionnaire</from-activity-id>
      <control-flow-case id="__13">
        <from-outcome>create</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>create</to-activity-id>
        <transition>slideRight</transition>
      </control-flow-case>
      <control-flow-case id="__14">
        <from-outcome>list</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>list</to-activity-id>
      </control-flow-case>
      <control-flow-case id="__15">
        <from-outcome>search</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>search</to-activity-id>
      </control-flow-case>
      <control-flow-case id="__16">
        <from-outcome>report</from-outcome>
        <to-activity-id>reports</to-activity-id>
      </control-flow-case>
    </control-flow-rule>
    <page-flow-scope-behavior>
      <push-new/>
    </page-flow-scope-behavior>
  </task-flow-definition>
</adfc-mobile-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AMX component that has the action attribute.
Example:

```
 <amx:commandLink id="commandLink1" text="create Questionnaire" action="create" />
```

Where action is the name of you control flow case in your task flow.